# Access violation when writing into 0000057C ollydbg

Tags: c++, error-handling, ollydbg

ollydbg access violation when writing into 0000057C
Below code give me error as it write null empty exp date how i can pass this or make it type fixed date

```
00ABF6C1     C683 7C050000 >MOV BYTE PTR DS:[EBX+57C],1
00ABF6C8   . 8BC3           MOV EAX,EBX
00ABF6CA   . E8 BDAD94FF    CALL playerb2.0040A48C
00ABF6CF   > 33C0           XOR EAX,EAX
00ABF6D1   . 5A             POP EDX
00ABF6D2   . 59             POP ECX
00ABF6D3   . 59             POP ECX
00ABF6D4   . 64:8910        MOV DWORD PTR FS:[EAX],EDX
00ABF6D7   . 68 ECF6AB00    PUSH playerb2.00ABF6EC
00ABF6DC   > 8D45 FC        LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
00ABF6DF   . E8 A8AD94FF    CALL playerb2.0040A48C
00ABF6E4   . C3             RETN
00ABF6E5   .^E9 42A394FF    JMP playerb2.00409A2C
00ABF6EA   .^EB F0          JMP SHORT playerb2.00ABF6DC
00ABF6EC   . 5B             POP EBX
00ABF6ED   . 59             POP ECX
00ABF6EE   . 5D             POP EBP
00ABF6EF   . C3             RETN
```

Comment: I guess 00ABF6C1     C683 7C050000 >MOV BYTE PTR DS:[EBX+57C],1 mean it write the exp data into 0000057C    ??? can i make it pass writing or at least type different date

Comment: This is lacking a lot of context. Where does C++ fit into this? And what are these dates, and what specifically is a "null empty exp date"?

Comment: This question belongs in https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/